# Sorting by prefix and suffix in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a list of values in an Excel table (that's important, as I want to keep the functionality of the table) that are like this:

```
A/1
A/2
A/6
A/11
A125

B/1
B/2
B/3
B/4
B/10
B/11
B/38
B/110
```

When sorted it keeps the prefix sort (obviously), but then the numbers are all messed up (A/125 is before A/2 etc). Which is useless to me. What can I do to force it to sort after the letter (one or two characters) prefix first, then by number. Is that even possible within one cell?

Comment: You will either need to parse(separate) the parts and then sort on the helper columns.  Or change the data so all the "numbers" have the same number of digits: `A/001`,`A/0002`.  There is no quick method.

Comment: I think helper column will be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Format your data to include leading zeroes. For example:

```
=LEFT([@Original],2)&RIGHT("000"&MID([@Original],3,LEN([@Original])),3)
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about it, but these IDs are referred to in another program/model, so I would rather keep them in the original form.

Comment: @Warmaker just use the new column for sorting, while keeping the original column for your referencing.